# source images served by image server

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are lots of images that I would like to display using jquery, jstree and html. All image names are like this.

```
<node_id>-serverA_cpu.png
<node_id>-serverA_mem.png
<node_id>-serverB_cpu.png
<node_id>-serverB_mem.png
```

When I create the images externally, I give them a unique identifier called node_id which is the same text as in jstree node_id. When the user clicks on a node on jstree, I display every image that starts with that node id. It works well when web server and the images are on the same server. I do this

```
var Img_CPU = "img/"+node_id+"-Server_cpu.png";
var Img_Mem = "img/"+node_id+"-Server_mem.png";
```

etc

I then use jquery function to load the image if exist and source it, as below:

```
$(function () 
{ 
    var myImage1 = new Image(); 
    $(myImage1).load(function () 
          {                   
        $("#div1").html(myImage1);      

          })  

          .attr('src', Img_CPU).error(function()
            {
        $('#div1').html("").css({"border": "", "margin": "0"});
           })
});
```

this all works great when images are located on the same server as the IIS. What if my images were on another server that could be access via http. How can I source the images if they are on a separate server?

Comment: What is another domain url? please give some example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When images are on another domain you must change your image url to the absolute url

```
var Img_CPU = "img/"+node_id+"-Server_cpu.png";
to
var Img_CPU = "http://anotherdomain.com/img/"+node_id+"-Server_cpu.png";
```

If it still not work then I think this is cross domain policy (although this should not apply to image)

Comment: I tried this same mehtod before and it was not working for some reason. But I just did this and it is working. Thank you.